# Model that takes grouping factor into account is a significantly better fit, but no significant differences between groups...unusual?

Tags: r, fixed-effects-model

I'm dealing with a dataset that comprises ~30 groups of observations. In each group, we measured independent and dependent variables a certain number of times. If I plot the relationship between independent and dependent variables for each group separately, I get something like this (showing just 4 of the groups here, with the independent variable on the X and dependent on the Y):

[image]

My ultimate goal is to determine whether the effect of the independent variable (i.e., the slope of a linear regression `dep ~ ind`) is significantly different between groups, and to quantify which groups have the largest/smallest effects.

To do this, I've put every data point into a single dataframe, with a column indicating the group it came from. Then, I ran the following model, calculating an interaction term for `group`.

`lm1 = lm(dep ~ ind * group, data=df)`

To figure out whether a model that accounts for differences between groups is a better fit than a model that doesn't, I also fit the following model:

`lm2 = lm(dep ~ ind, data=df)`

And then I compared the two models using ANOVA:

`anova(lm1, lm2)`

The p-value of the ANOVA is about 1e-5, suggesting that the model that takes `group` into account is the better fit.

However, I've also done the following to figure out if effects in particular groups are larger/smaller than in others:

`library(lsmeans)
lst <- lstrends(lm1, "group", var="ind")
pairs(lst)`

Here, I'm performing pair-wise comparisons of effects between all groups, and after correcting for multiple testing, none of the pairwise comparisons are significantly different.

To me, this suggests that *overall*, a model that takes group into account is a better fit. But because the number of data points in each group is small (~8-10), the per-group regressions produce large confidence intervals, making it difficult to find significant differences between groups.

Am I thinking about this correctly?

(Apologies if a similar question has been asked before, I couldn't find any questions that directly addressed my concerns.)

Comment: I don't know what `lsmeans` does but why are you not looking at the `lm1` output? The linear model will give you the p-values for all the tested hypotheses.

Comment: It *is* possible for an overall effect to be significant and yet have no significant pairwise comparisons. However, another aspect of this is an adjustment is made to the P values for multiplicity, and it is pretty drastic when protecting against making *any* type I errors among those 435 comparisons, as is done with the default adjustment method (Tukey).

Comment: PS As of Oct 10, **lsmeans** will be archived on CRAN. Use **emmeans** instead.